# Compile MJPG Streamer Error

Tags: camera, webcam, motion

I followed up some Tutorial to install MJPG-Streamer but somehow it will not compile. Anybody know what is wrong?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev imagemagick libv4l-dev
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/files/latest/download
sudo mv download mjpg.tar.gz
tar  xzvf mjpg.tar.gz
cd   mjpg-streamer-r63
make
```

Error

```
spcav4l.c:1117:14: error: ‘BASE_VIDIOCPRIVATE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
spcav4l.c:1117:14: error: invalid operands to binary << (have ‘int *’ and ‘int’)
spcav4l.c:1117:14: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int *’)
spcav4l.c:1117:14: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘int *’ and ‘unsigned int’)
spcav4l.c:1117:14: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ioctl’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/ioctl.h:42:12: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'spcav4l.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [spcav4l.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/mjpg/mjpg-streamer-r63/plugins/input_gspcav1'
Makefile:55: recipe for target 'input_gspcav1.so' failed
make: *** [input_gspcav1.so] Error 2
```

The Full Error Log can be find here: http://pastebin.com/Nuqee6Jh

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer.git

sudo apt-get install cmake libjpeg8-dev

cd mjpg-streamer-experimental

make

sudo make install
```

Here is how to run it (in the "mjpg-streamer-experimental" directory):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.

./mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www" -i "input_raspicam.so"
```

Or for a different fps and resolution, try:

```
./mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www" -i "input_raspicam.so -x 1280 -y 720 -fps 15 -ex night"
```

To check the output on a web browser:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/stream.html    (change 127.0.0.1 to your own ip address)

Comment: Thanks. Note that you could also edit your original answer (there's an edit link below it), which is preferable.